# What are these little things on the evacuation slide?

Tags: evacuation, emergency-procedures

I marked them with black circles. What are they for? 
[image]

[Source](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-oHdmyDdrYAs/UUR0gIJO8-I/AAAAAAAAStg/1tMMdmyJCG8/s1600/Slide.jpg) (modified)

Comment: in raft mode I'd guess a place for the tent to prop itself up with

Comment: Those are where the ladies hang their hand-bags on the way down.  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@ratchet freak is correct. The protrusions are canopy poles, where the canopy in the evacuation slide/raft is propped up. The image below shows a canopy propped on them.

[image: Canopy]

Image from [tulmar.com](http://www.tulmar.com/images/site_client/documents/download_center/Manuals/Training_Slides/Single_and_Dual_Lane_Generic_Training_Slide.pdf)

From the document:

> The canopy is supported in the center in 4 places by inflatable yellow “CANOPY END SUPPORTS” and “CANOPY CENTER SUPPORTS”, and supported along the sides by 14 numbered supports on the top of the slides inflatable structure.

Here's a closeup of the support from the same document.

[image: Canopy support]

Comment: Has there ever been an actual event where a slide was required to be used in this way?

Comment: where is the actual canopy stored?